# Здравствуйте. Недавно начал изучать указатели в c++ , и столкнулся с проблемой. Почему указателю на char* temp присваивается строка , а не адрес

Tags: c++

По идее туда должен же присваиваться адрес. И почему не возникает ошибки

Comment: Присваивается адрес. Адрес строки.

Comment: Вообще не изучал C++, но вы бы привели тут доказательство (т.е. что вас заставило так думать - код с выводом, например) таких интересных присвоений:-)

Comment: но при выводе указателя temp на консоль выводится именно строка

Comment: Потому что для std::cout и char* есть переопределенный оператор вывода. И он, как художник, так выводит.

Comment: Код покажите...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При присваивании чего-либо чему-либо обычно (это не всегда так, но для простых типов практически без исключений) создается копия присваемого значения, и записывается в присваеваемую переменную.

Например,

```
int x;
x = y;
```

Здесь значение из переменной `y` копируется в переменную `x`.

Когда рассматриваются строки в стиле C, то есть просто массивы char'ов, оканчивающиеся нулевым символом, то такая строка значением не является. Значением является ее адрес, то есть место, где этот массив лежит в памяти.

Так что когда вы пишете что-то вроде

```
const char * s = "Hello, world";
```

строка `"Hello, world"` хранится где-то в памяти, а в переменную `s` записывается ее адрес.

Именно поэтому никакие действия наподобие "сложения" или "сравнения" строк не дают ожидаемого некоторыми результата, потому что это адреса, а не содержимое.

Именно в этом смысле указателю "присваивается строка".

Другое дело, что С++ сделан совместимым с С насколько это возможно, и потому иногда рассматривает строки, которые являются массивами символов, не так, как прочие массивы. В первую очередь это относится к выводу на экран. В 99,9..% (не знаю, сколько там девяток надо) случаев при выводе программист хочет вывести именно строку, на которую указывает указатель, а не адрес. Поэтому сделано так, что в

```
int * a; char * s;
....
cout << a;
cout << s;
```

первый вывод будет выводить *адрес*, а второй - *строку*, находящуюся по этому адресу.

Если нужно вывести именно адрес, надо привести указатель к другому виду, например,

```
cout << (void*)s;
```